# How to check if a float value is empty in a POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, http-post

I'm wondering how i should check if a POST request sends data or not when i send a float value, i try to do this with if statements to all values i give in the post request but i can't use an if statement on a float value because it can't be null. here is my post request. it might seem really ugly to most people but i'm not familiar with ASP.NET MVC

```
[HttpPut("Product/Edit/{productid}")]
    public IActionResult ProductEdit(string token, int productid, [FromBody]Product p)
    {
        bool RoleId = JWTValidator.RoleIDTokenValidation(token);
        var edit = _context.products.Find(productid);
        if (RoleId)
        {
            if (p.Name != null)
            {
                edit.Name = p.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                edit.Name = edit.Name;
            }
            if (p.Description != null)
            {
                edit.Description = p.Description;
            }
            else
            {
                edit.Description = edit.Description;
            }
            edit.Price = p.Price;
            if (p.FirstImg != null)
            {
                edit.FirstImg = p.FirstImg;
            }
            else
            {
                edit.FirstImg = edit.FirstImg;
            }
            edit.Stock = p.Stock;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.products.Update(edit);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return Ok("Product updated");
        }

        return Unauthorized();

    }
```

Price is float and stock in int, so i try to do it with an if statement like i do with the others but it can't be done because of above said reason. i tried this(Code snipped underneath this text) but when i do this and send a POST request my DB will update with an empty value for price and stock.

```
if(p.Price.ToString() != null)
            {
            edit.Price = p.Price;
            } else {
                edit.Price = edit.Price;
            }
```

the if statement on all of these check if the value that get send with the post request is empty or not otherwise the original value in the DB will be maintained.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm happy to learn seeing how i'm a student so any remarks would be fine.

Comment: Do you really need the `else` part code ? The property value is already there. Also consider using ModelValidation which does the validation for you.

Comment: @Shyju yes I need the else, otherwise it will send an empty string if I don't pass a value to that attribute, for example if i make a post request where i just wanna update the description i wouldn't wanna update stock and price as well. and the if statements make it so that that isn't the case when i don't pass the other values in the POST request. But i actually haven't tested it so I'm going to try it without the else but that still doesn't solve my problem. also i'm already using validation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you mentioned price is float type so by default it will be 0.0f (if you don't save any value to first time) so just compare with price > 0

change your code like

```
if(p.Price>0)
        {
        edit.Price = p.Price;
        } else {
            edit.Price = edit.Price;
        }
```

Comment: What if it's a discount and a negative price?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I do not think a price input would be negative. if there is any discount field (though there is no sign of it) then it should be adjusted from server end. you are not going to save price amount as negative value in real life condition

Comment: We aren't working with discounts for this project, but if we did we would have done it differently then safe the discount price in the controller, but thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @TaskinKhaleque you haven't worked in Finance if you don't think negative dollar and unit prices are used. Infact many accounting systems rely on negative dollar values. Eg a balance sheet.

Answer (score 0):

As Taskin mentioned, price is float type so by default it will be 0.
So try setting your price like below.

```
edit.Price = p.Price != edit.Price ? p.Price : edit.Price;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this .

```
  if (p.Price.Equals(null))
        {
            edit.Price = edit.Price;
        }
        else
        {
            edit.Price = p.Price;
        }
```